# Keras Reshape: total size of the new array must be unchanged

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm, reshape

I'm trying to use Keras Reshape function API to reshape the output of a glove embedding (4D shape: (?, 9, 20, 100)) down to 3D (?, 9, 2000). However, when I tried Reshape((9, 2000))(text_layer), an error pops up and says total size of the new array must be unchanged, even though 9 * 20 * 100 = 9 * 2000. Any ideas why? Code is attached.

```
text = Input(shape=(9, news_text.shape[1]), name='text')
text_layer = Embedding(
    embedding_matrix.shape[0],
    embedding_matrix.shape[1],
    weights=[embedding_matrix],
    input_length=news_text.shape[1]
)(text)
text_layer = Reshape((9, text_layer.shape[2] * text_layer.shape[3]))(text_layer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the **`input_length`** parameter from the `Embedding` layer.

It is strange and I don't know the reason but when you indicate the parameter `input_length` the error is thrown.

Anyway, the `Embedding` layer receives the dimension of the `Input` layer. It seems that the parameter `input_length` has a very specific use, to know the dimension of the tensor after using a `Flatten` layer, etc.

In this case, the `Embedding` layer obtains the shape of the output tensor from the input tensor, ignoring the `input_length` parameter.

(If you set an invalid value does not throw error until you add the next layer. Note that the `input_lenght` and the result `shape`):

```
>>> inp = Input(shape=(9,20))
>>> emb = Embedding(100,100, input_length=84) (inp)
>>> emb
<tf.Tensor 'embedding_5/embedding_lookup:0' shape=(?, 9, 20, 100) dtype=float32>
>>> res = Reshape((9,2000)) (emb)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ...
```

However, it seems that the `input_length` parameter is in conflict when you add the `Reshape` layer.

**Finally:**

```
text = Input(shape=(9, news_text.shape[1]), name='text')
text_layer = Embedding(
    embedding_matrix.shape[0],
    embedding_matrix.shape[1],
    weights=[embedding_matrix],
)(text)
text_layer = Reshape((9, text_layer.shape[2] * text_layer.shape[3]))(text_layer)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! However, once the input length is removed, the resulting reshaped text_layer is fed into an LSTM which threw an error: 
`float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Dimension'`
on 
`scale /= max(1., float(fan_in + fan_out) / 2) in keras initializer.py` 
Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. It would be necessary to see the code and the indicated parameters.

Since adding the new question by editing this post would make it difficult to handle the answers in the community, I would suggest creating a new question.